# Generic Insert Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created generic insert code for database insert in C# (for datatype like text date number etc not for all datatypes)
now I m planning to write generic insert stored procedure in oracle
My question is that "is there anything that we can do with programming languages like C# or JAVA that we cant do with stored procedures for generic insert statement"
also please suggest if anybody has already done that.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic insert statement"?  You can certainly write a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL to generate an `INSERT` statement based on data in the data dictionary and to bind data that is passed in.  But it would be very unlikely that this would be a good idea-- dynamic SQL increases the complexity of your code substantially and causes a ton of compilation errors to become much more difficult to detect runtime errors.

Comment: @justin : agreed that its complicated but my manager wants very less coding effort if we wants to move from ASP to JSP or any other language.. So i came up with stored procedure.. is there any way in your mind please let me know

Comment: A single stored procedure generating and executing dynamic SQL at runtime does not reduce coding effort over simple stored procedures that contain appropriate static SQL particularly if testing, debugging, and maintenance are included.  There are plenty of ORM tools out there, there are plenty of frameworks for generating packages with CRUD procedures for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please stop. This is a solved problem. There's plenty of tools available that will do what you want and much more, and in a more elegant way.

For example, have a look at ORM tools like [(N)Hibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), there are many others. There are also more light-weight options such as [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data), [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive), [dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net), ...

Comment: @jeroend: I m sorry for misleading you... I want less coding effort for moving code from one language to another like ASP to JSP so i thought of stored procedure... also to make it simple i thought of generic insert statement

Comment: Thanks tools suggested by you are very good. I will definately try some in my projects :)